# SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! when calling multiple times

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following spark configuration:

```python
return SparkSession.builder \
    .master("yarn") \
    .appName("my_application) \
    .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0") \
    .config("spark.driver.host", host) \
    .config("spark.driver.port", port) \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "4G") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "8G") \
    .config("spark.blockManager.port", port_block_manager) \
    .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

From spark im loading a dataframe to pandas. Im using this in a microservice to provide data to a frontend. When there is only one request everything is working fine but if two different frontends requesting the same thing at the same time I get an error:

```python
17/09/21 13:04:56 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/09/21 13:04:56 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
17/09/21 13:04:56 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__service__.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "__service__", line 113, in get_pos_enriched
    spark = get_spark_session("adjusted_sales.temp_data_read")
  File "__service__", line 61, in get_spark_session
    .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true") \
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1428, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I thought setting `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true` would do the trick her but obviously not. How can I get a `SparkSession` independent from the amount of usages? Can I create a separate session or context for each usage?

Comment: Just for the record: Spark never actually supported multiple contexts (`allowMultipleContexts` just avoided an exception, but allowed for undefined behaviors) and most likely won't support in the future. That being said builder alone should just return existing session so either problem is not directly related (like lack of resources) or you're hitting some concurrency bug. One way or another getting exact exit reason would be a good idea.

Comment: @zero323 Please tell me more about **allowMultipleContexts just avoided an exception but allowed for undefined behaviors** , or some document

Comment: I'd recommend [SPARK-2243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243). I also remember some answer by Josh Rosen posted on SO.